# Understanding base::identical() -- why is it "safer"?

Tags: r

I have always heard that `identical()` is "safer" than `==`. But playing around with them both it seems like the desired result is obtained by the latter and not the former. I'm assuming this has something to do with the attributes of the object generated by `nrow()` but it would be nice with a clarification as to why this happens in the example below:

```
> identical(3653510+2751069, 6404579)
[1] TRUE
> identical((3653510+nrow(df)), nrow(df2))
[1] FALSE
> nrow(df)
[1] 2751069
> nrow(df2)
[1] 6404579
> nrow(df2)-nrow(df)
[1] 3653510
> (3653510+nrow(df))==nrow(df2)
[1] TRUE
```

So to summarize, I have two questions:

1. What's going on with `identical()`?
2. What do we mean be saying a function is "safer" to use in this context?

Comment: Try to use `all.equal`.  `identical` also checks attributes

Comment: ... so it is likely the difference between `numeric` and `int` i.e. `class(3653510+2751069); class(6404579); class(3653510+nrow(df)); class(nrow(df2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be an attribute difference. e.g.

```
n1 <- 2751069
n2 <- 6404579
identical((3653510 + n1), n2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Both are numeric class.  If we change one of them to `integer`, it returns `FALSE`

```
n2 <- 6404579L
identical((3653510 + n1), n2)
#[1] FALSE
```

With `all.equal`, we can also specify `check.attributes = FALSE`

```
all.equal((3653510 + n1), n2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```